# Не открывается папка с React приложением через команду 'code .'

Tags: cmd, visual-studio-code

Как открыть только что созданный проект create-react-app в vscode через командную строку ? Команда 'code .' не работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Чтобы команда code открывала vscode из командной строки, нужно папку vscode добавить в переменную окружения PATH.